# Hazelcast serialization between cluster members

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have a configuration class which store in hz IMap
This configuration class is part of 1-st instance member
**P.S** members are two different applications.

```
public class AConfiguration implements Serializable {
private String name;
private ApplicationSystem appSystem; //enum
private Map<String, ConfigParams> config params;
//getters setters;
}
```

This configuration is pushed to IMap from 1-st cluster Member as Object

My goal is to see this configuration in another module

How to serialize that object in 2-nd member instance? 
If a invoke

```
IMap<Key, Object> d = hazelcastInstance.getMap("CACHE");
```

I got `com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.hazelcastserializationexception`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that inner objects of `AConfiguration` are also serializable. Also, it is recommended to put `serialVersionUID` as stated in [official hazelcast docs](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.1/manual/html-single/index.html#implementing-java-serializable-and-externalizable).

Comment: all of the nested objects implement serializable and contains serialVersionUID.
AConfiguration class does not exist in 2-nd instance.

Comment: [This code](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/serialization/hazelcast-airlines/the-code/src/test/java/com/hazelcast/samples/serialization/hazelcast/airlines/V1FlightTest.java#L27) allows you test deserialization/serialization of a `java.io.Serializable` object without Hazelcast. If that doesn't work perhaps you can add an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).. The line you show `IMap<Key, Object> d = hazelcastInstance.getMap("CACHE");` is retrieving the Hazelcast map reference so hasn't attempted to deserialize your entry.

Comment: This small code snipper how i go that https://github.com/imbaTapac/hazelcast-caching/tree/master/src/main/java/hazelcast/sample